# Blocking going to other webpages throught url bar in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a fundamental problem with spring boot application. The start webpage is http://127.0.0.1:8080/login and after log in user is redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8080/MainMenu. Unfortunatelly it is also possible to write in url bar http://127.0.0.1:8080/MainMenu and going there without authentication.
What is the main idea to block that action?

@edit
This is my configuration:

```
 package local.vlex.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "src/main/resources/static/assets/css/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

and Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/MainMenu")
    public ModelAndView correctCredentials(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("MainMenu");
        return mav;
    }
```

Sum up:
I would like to block going to other sites without authentication - if someone is not logged in then it should go 404 on everything other than /login

Comment: Show us at least your security configuration.

Comment: `antMatchers("/MainMenu").permitAll()`. You allowed specifically all requests to MainMenu. Also, if the answer of Maruf doesn't fit your requirements, you should specify them. We cannot guess what you want to achieve.

Comment: @dunni
Can you take a look at edited code?
Now only "/" is allowed but it will redirect to "/login". Unfortunatelly now I can go to any site from url bar

Comment: If that's not what you want, tell us what you want. Do you want to allow specific pages? Do you only want to block MainMenu?

Comment: I want to block all websites without log in. If someone is not logged in then I don't want to let him go to /MainMenu, /ProductPage, /ChangePassword and so on first he should go to /login and only if he authenticate then can go to other sites mentioned above.

Comment: But that's what you already have with your solution, isn't it? Or can you still access those pages without authentication? Or do you want, that the user gets a 403 (Access denied) response, when he is not logged in and tries to open those pages, instead of being redirected to the login page?

Comment: Access denied would be cool without authentcation. I can still access every page without authentication now. Actually this code which I posted do nothing - it should allow only "/" and "/login" but I can write "/MainMenu" and easily go there without log in

Comment: "I want to block all websites"... I just have to mention here that we're talking about your web application only. A spring app, naturally, won't have any control to other websites besides this one.

Comment: @eis
true, should have mention that I mean everything on 10.1.2.5 - production server. I am aware that I cannot block facebook.com or other sites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if someone is not logged in then it should go 404 on everything other
>   than /login

This is a bit pecular requirement. What is usually done is that people get redirected to login page on all other urls than login, or get `401 Unauthorized` or `403 Forbidden`. However, it's not hard to do this one either.

You mentioned you need your static resources (css, js, images) in the assets directory as well, so given that, this should work:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class YourSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/assets/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND))
                ;
    }
}
```

Using

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

in Maven pom.xml

Note that there is also accessDeniedHandler() in exceptionHandling(), but that seems to only fire when user is already authenticated but denied access, so you'd need authenticationentrypoint for your use case.

---

Addition:

Sometimes having a custom authentication entrypoint messes the existing entry point handler. That is the case at least if you use default spring-generated form login. One way to go around that is to specify your entrypoint to only match urls that are *not* matching your authentication handler url, like this:

```
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher;

// snip...

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/assets/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND),
                        new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login")) )
            .and()
                .formLogin()
            ;
}
```

Comment: static are still missing but tried to login and got: Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found. After adding http.csrf().disable() I got: Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Sep 18 11:10:23 CEST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: @Michu93 you need to replace in my example the `/images` path with your own static paths as you didn't tell us which one are those. Isn't 404 error page what you requested?

Comment: @Michu93 I guess you are using `assets` folder so added that as well to my example.

Comment: My bad with assets, yes it does find it now!
There is still problem with logging - even when I pass correct login and password I get 
'Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Sep 18 11:21:39 CEST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available '
but I am just getting login and password to @PostMapping(/login) and check if it's ok. I should use some spring security methods, shouldn't I?

Comment: @Michu93 that means your login, possibly your login form is not written correctly as it doesn't provide you with authentication. Your login form is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Something like `http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/do_login")` is needed if you want to use spring-generated login page. I can add it to your answer if you want.

Comment: you are right. My problem with accessing unallowed sites is done. I'll take a look at it but I cannot use default login page. Thanks

Comment: Sure! Have to wait 20hours to award bounty. Answer accepted

Comment: I also added into my answer a workaround for cases where custom authentication entrypoint configuration messes the existing configuration. Might come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code, It will block all the request except "/" & "/login"

```
  @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
        }

       @Override
      public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                    "/css/**",
                    "/js/**",
                    "/lib/**",
                    "/video/**",
                    "/images/**"
            );
       }

    }
```

And add WebConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .setCachePeriod(31556926)
                .resourceChain(true);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the security dependency in your pom.xml file.

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: well, now whatever I type after  http://127.0.0.1:8080/ it always go to  http://127.0.0.1:8080/login. In HomeController I have: @GetMapping("/")
 public String startHtml() {
  return "redirect:/login";
 }

Comment: It also lost css so I had to add: .antMatchers("/", "sec/main/resources/static/assets/css/**").permitAll() and @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=HomeController.class)
but it destroyed sping security - again all webpages are allowed in url bar

Comment: Still can go on other sites by typing adress in url bar ;/

Comment: Edit my answer, please check it. @Michu93

Comment: still doesn't work, I relaunched application, typed http://127.0.0.1:8080/MainMenu into url bar and went there without problems ;/
@Maruf Hassan

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you have spring-security dependencies on classpath, this is a working example from my code.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**")
                .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
```

This blocks me from any other requests than '/' or 'login' or 'loginPage' etc. with Authorization.

Follow that with ignoring the static ones, css, js etc.,

If this still doesn't work, for now try working on blocking the page alone:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/MainMenu")
                .authenticated();
```

The above would give idea what's happening. Dependency issue or something like that.

Comment: It is nearly the same what I have but there are two problems with it.
First - it looses css, images, js files, second - it doesn't go to 404

Comment: When I added blocking MainMenu it works - 403 Access denied but that's not exacly what I am looking for. I would like to allow user to go on /login but throw 403/404 on every other subsite ie. /MainMenu

Comment: Yep. So no issue with dependency or anything like that. The basic security just works fine. On the loosing of css,images, I have mentioned to add to ignore them. Same answer as @Maruf has given to ignore static ones. Will it work then?

Comment: No, it's not. I have alredy tried both ways 1) by .antMatchers("/", "src/main/resources/static/assets/**").permitAll() and 2) by WebConfig from @Maruf answer but in both cases I lose images, css and everything from /src/main/resources/static/assets/**

Comment: `webSecurityBuilder.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**")` should help you?

Comment: seems like I am missing something in pom.xml because 'webSecurityBuilder' cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: That's the instance of WebSecurity. My bad - use as `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**")`, if you go by Maruf's example.

Comment: The answer from @eis works perfectly. Thanks for help anyway!